# Issue in getting iteration data from rally API

Tags: rally, code-rally

I am using following url to get the iteration data from rally.
I then parse the json data received.

def **query** = URLEncoder.encode("(Project.Name contains \"1 Prime Infrastructure\")", "UTF-8")

def **rallyURL** = "https://us1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iteration?query="+query+"&fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=200"

The issue is it giving 0 records. But when i change the name to some other project the data comes.

Probably it is because of the default workspace for my username and password. I want project data from different workspace. 
I have access to all this workspace.

can someone tell how to set the workspace before making an api call so that i can get the iteration data ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply include a workspace parameter in your url to override the default:

```
&workspace=/workspace/12345
```

You can also always further refine your results to a specific project:

```
&project=/project/12345
```

Or to a specific hierarchy:

```
&projectScopeUp=true
&projectScopeDown=true
```

Comment: IterationCumulativeFlow data does not return defects which are in current iterations and has points . do you have any solution for this ?? I have show this defect in iteration burndown chart .